# Spring 3.0 FileUpload only with POST?

Tags: spring, file-upload, spring-mvc

I am trying to upload a File with one parameter using spring 3.

This is my controller method which should enable this service:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers="content-type=multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadImageWithJsonParamater(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestParam String json, @RequestParam MultipartFile customerSignFile) {
    //...
}
```

The problem is, that the server cannot dispatch to this method:
MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'json' is not present

If I change the RequestMethod from PUT to POST, everything  is fine. So does anybody know the problem?

It seems that it isn't allowed to transmit form-data via PUT.

I debugged a little bit and the following method returns false in the PUT case but true in the POST case:

```
public boolean isMultipart(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return (request != null && ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request));
}
```

I would appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really do a PUT, or do you use a HiddenHttpMethodFilter?

Comment: The reasson I took PUT is, that I wanted to simulate a form-data upload but according to REST, not creating a new object (POST) but updating an existing one (PUT)

Comment: it seams that you did not understand the question. Spring normaly fakes the PUT and DELETE requests with help of the HiddenHttpMethodFilter. (Because some Brosers do not support PUT) So my question is simple, do you really really use PUT and not some faked POST?

Comment: Ah okay, now I know what you mean. No, I am not using a HiddenHttpMethodFilter since the client sending those requests isn't a  browser. I do have control of the way I am requesting the server (PUT/GET/POST...)

Comment: So I recommend sometink like Andrei Bodnarescu, use the "HiddenHttpMethodFilter" am POST and Parameter "_method" = PUT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send form data via PUT as per the HTML standard. You can only send files via PUT, and in this case they're send more efficiently then with POST (because you no longer have all the multi-part overhead), but in order for you PUT listening server side component to actually receive a file via PUT you have to make sure that you actually send a PUT command to it (via javascript for instance). Here's an example that uses JQuery:

```
$('#file_upload').fileUpload({
    namespace: 'file_upload',
    url: '/path',
    method: 'PUT'
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I suggested. In the corresponding RFC for the multipart/form-data file upload they are just talking about POSTing data, never PUTing it. That's what lead me to your suggestion, too. The reasson I took PUT is, that I wanted to simulate a form-data upload but according to REST, not creating a new object (POST) but updating an existing one (PUT)

Answer (score 5):

I run into the same problem.
My solution was implementing an `ExtendedMultipartResolver` which accept multiparts sent via http method PUT as well.
Just copy the [`CommonsMultipartResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.1.SPR-10138-httpservletbean-environment-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartResolver.html) code, rename the class and change the implementation of the `isMultipart()` function to your needs:

```
private boolean isMultipartContent(HttpServletRequest request) {
  String httpMethod = request.getMethod().toLowerCase();
  // test for allowed methods here...
  String contentType = request.getContentType();
  return (contentType != null && contentType.toLowerCase().startsWith("multipart"));
}


public boolean isMultipart(HttpServletRequest request) {
      return (request != null && isMultipartContent(request));
}
```

You could check for POST, PUT or other HTTP methods here. In my case, all methods will be accepted, 
as my controller annotations will filter to the allowed methods.

Dont forget to configure the bean in the spring web context:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="sample.package.ExtendedMultipartResolver"/>
```

hope that helps.

cheers
chris

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this using spring's [HiddenHttpMethodFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html), but you will need to ensure that you put a Spring [MultipartFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/MultipartFilter.html) before the HiddenHttpMethodFilter in your web.xml filter chain.

For example: In your web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>multipartResolverBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>filterMultipartResolver</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>/*</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>/*</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then in your spring-config.xml add a reference to CommonsMultipartResolver:

```
<bean id="filterMultipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

Note that, if you don't add the spring-config.xml entry your MultipartFilter will default to   using a MultipartResolver that uses servlet spec 3.0 implementation and will throw error like: *NoSuchMethodError HttpServletRequest.getParts()* if you're not using 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a slightly different solution, inspired by http://rugal.ga/development/2015/10/03/uploading-file-other-than-post/, and close to a previous post:

```
public class ExtendedMultipartResolver extends CommonsMultipartResolver {

@Override
public boolean isMultipart(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return (request != null && isMultipartContent(request));
}

/**
 * Extends ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent() behavior to allow PUT requests as multipart.
 * 
 * @param request
 *            The servlet request to be evaluated. Must be non-null.
 *
 * @return <code>true</code> if the request is multipart; <code>false</code> otherwise.
 * @see org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload#isMultipartContent
 */
public static final boolean isMultipartContent(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpMethod httpMethod = HttpMethod.valueOf(request.getMethod());
    if (HttpMethod.POST != httpMethod && HttpMethod.PUT != httpMethod) {
        return false;
    }
    return FileUploadBase.isMultipartContent(new ServletRequestContext(request));
}
```

}

Nothing new here, except that my code relies on org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.isMultipartContent(RequestContext) instead of duplicating its content.

Now, if you ever needed to implement unit tests of file upload services, you might have used org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload() in the following way:

```
@Test
public void testUploadFilePost() throws Exception {
    MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile(...);
    String url = ...;
    mockMvc.perform(fileUpload(url).file(multipartFile)).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

The above code can only issue POST requests, because of the way org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder is implemented. In order to unit test a PUT file upload, you may be interested in the following code:

```
private static final RequestPostProcessor PUT_REQUEST_POST_PROCESSOR = new RequestPostProcessor() {

    @Override
    public MockHttpServletRequest postProcessRequest(MockHttpServletRequest request) {
        request.setMethod(HttpMethod.PUT.name());
        return request;
    }

};

private static MockHttpServletRequestBuilder putFileUpload(String url, MockMultipartFile multipartFile,
        Object... urlVariables) {
    return fileUpload(url, urlVariables).file(multipartFile).with(PUT_REQUEST_POST_PROCESSOR);
}
```

The test can now be adapted the following way:

```
@Test
public void testUploadFilePut() throws Exception {
    MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile(...);
    String url = ...;
    mockMvc.perform(putFileUpload(url, multipartFile)).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```