# RESTful PUT with file upload and form data in Spring MVC

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, put

I am using Spring MVC to expose some RESTful web services. One of the operations calls for a RESTful PUT operation when a form is submitted.

However, the form is no ordinary form in that it contains a file input along with regular inputs such as text and checkboxes.

I have configured Spring to work with RESTful PUT and DELETE by adding the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` in the `web.xml`. In my forms, i have a hidden `_method` parameter being sent as well.

All this works fine for DELETE, PUT without file upload, etc. When I try to do a PUT with file upload and form data, it gives me a `405`.

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported
```

My controller method looks like this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/cars/{carId}", method = PUT, headers = "content-type=multipart/form-data")
public String updateCar(@PathVariable("carId") String carId, CarForm form) {
    // save and return the right view.
}
```

My HTML form looks like this:

```
<form action="<c:url value='/admin/cars/${car.id}'/>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
    <input type="text" name="carName" value="${car.name}" />
    <input type="file" name="photo" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Is what I am trying to achieve doable at all using PUT? If so, how to make Spring MVC understand that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add [`MultipartFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/MultipartFilter.html) to enable file uploads **before** `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` in your web.xml (as written in `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` API docs, [see NOTE](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html)).

Also:

> Note: This filter is an alternative to using `DispatcherServlet`'s
>   `MultipartResolver` support, for example for web applications with
>   custom web views which do not use Spring's web MVC, **or for custom
>   filters applied before a Spring MVC `DispatcherServlet` (e.g.
>   `HiddenHttpMethodFilter`)**. In any case, this filter should not be
>   combined with servlet-specific multipart resolution.

*(from MF's docs, emphasis mine)*

Also, **`MultipartResolver`'s bean name must be `filterMultipartResolver` in order to MultipartFilter run properly** (or must be set via `<init-param>`).

**EDIT:**

<s>As I expected in my last comment, there's an issue with `CommonsMultipartResolver` which supports only POST method by default.</s> (Actually, *The method in the isMultipartContent comes in as POST even though it is a PUT as the MultipartFilter is declared before the HiddenHttpMethodFilter.* [as OP notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616928/restful-put-with-file-upload-and-form-data-in-spring-mvc/12617195#comment17013557_12617195).) Below is extednded class with slighlty modified [static method it uses originally](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.html#line.66):

```
public class PutAwareCommonsMultipartResolver extends CommonsMultipartResolver {

    private static final String MULTIPART = "multipart/";

    @Override
    public boolean isMultipart(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request != null && isMultipartContent(request);
    }

    /**
     * Utility method that determines whether the request contains multipart
     * content.
     * 
     * @param request The servlet request to be evaluated. Must be non-null.
     * 
     * @return <code>true</code> if the request is multipart; {@code false}
     * otherwise.
     * 
     * @see ServletFileUpload#isMultipartContent(HttpServletRequest)
     */
    public static final boolean isMultipartContent(HttpServletRequest request) {
        final String method = request.getMethod().toLowerCase();
        if (!method.equals("post") && !method.equals("put")) {
            return false;
        }
        String contentType = request.getContentType();
        if (contentType == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (contentType.toLowerCase().startsWith(MULTIPART)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Would it not work if the form bean uses `CommonsMultipartFile` for receiving the file input? I just tried with `MultipartFilter` but no joy.

Comment: I think that if you use `HiddenHttpMethodFilter`, `MultipartFilter` must be used and it _should_ work. Do you have [`CommonsMultipartResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartResolver.html) bean registered? `<bean id="filterMultipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
<property name="maxUploadSize">
<value>10000000</value>
</property>
</bean>`

Comment: Yes it has been declared. The file upload works if it is a regular `POST` scenario. It is only when I intend to use `PUT` that things go wrong.

Comment: `MultipartResolver`'s bean name must be `filterMultipartResolver` in order to `MultipartFilter` run properly (or must be set via `<init-param>`). Do you use `DispatcherServlet`'s name in `<servlet-name>` for both filters? Does MF comes first, before HHMF? (This works for me.) Also, can you turn Spring MVC's debug on and post output here?

Comment: Sorry, I revise my last comment, we use [`StandardServletMultipartResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/StandardServletMultipartResolver.html) for Servlet 3.0, not `CommonsMultipartFile`. Problem may be in it.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, it worked. But the solution was simply naming the bean `filterMultipartResolver`. The `method` in the `isMultipartContent` comes in as `POST` even though it is a `PUT` as the `MultipartFilter` is declared before the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter`. Perhaps, we need the `PutAware...` if we don't follow this order. Also, shouldn't it be `if (!method.equals("post") && !method.equals("put"))`?

Comment: Yeah, it should be `&&` there, untested code + basic first-order logic... ;)

Comment: Ok. This solves my problem with PUT. But then POST stops working!! Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `PUT` receives a binary stream and not multipart data. You can use `org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter` to make it work.

Comment: I am already using it as I have stated in my third paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested in an alternative solution (MultipartResolver with PUT method), to enforce Restful style for instance, you may have a look at [Spring 3.0 FileUpload only with POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981640/spring-3-0-fileupload-only-with-post/33658066#33658066).