# How to call put method in REST assured

Tags: java, web-services, junit, mockito, rest-assured

I have a put method that accepts inputstream. I want to call this method using rest assured in JUnit.

This is what I used:

```
with().body(inpustream).put("/service/1"); // i got error 404 forbidden.
```

Comment: 404 means Not Found, 403 means Forbidden.

Comment: It probably is 403, and that would probably indicate that the webserver is configured to not allow that method of request. I can fully understand that by default something as uncommon as PUT and DELETE is not enabled to prevent malicious intent.

Comment: Please tell me how to call put method using rest assured

Answer (score 1):

POST will return status code 201 and PUT will return 200, and POST will create a new resource but, PUT will update the existing resource. This means we will have to mention which resource we wish to update in the URI itself like below.

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;


public class PUTMethod {

    public static Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    @BeforeTest
    public void putdata(){
        map.put("userId", "2");
        map.put("id", "19");
        map.put("title", "this is projectdebug.com");
        map.put("body", "i am testing REST api with REST-Assured and sending a PUT request.");  
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
        RestAssured.basePath = "/posts/";
    }

    @Test
    public void testPUT(){
        given()
        .contentType("application/json")
        .body(map)
        .when()
        .put("/100")
        .then()
        .statusCode(200)
        .and()
        .body("title", equalTo("this is projectdebug.com"));        
    }
 }
```

Visit http://www.projectdebug.com/send-put-request-using-rest-assured/
for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are doing well but sending multipart through PUT is unsecured and is quite random (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9079). Amend your spring-security.xml to add a filter or use POST method in this case.

You can also try your code by calling another PUT webservice with no stream.

(And what is the error code ? 404 or 403 ?)

A similar problem solved by using MultipartFilter : [Spring 3.0 FileUpload only with POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981640/spring-3-0-fileupload-only-with-post)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following example, where it explains how to use `PUT` request using Rest Assured:

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import com.jayway.restassured.response.Response;

public class GetStatusCodeTest {
  @BeforeClass
  public void setBaseUri () {
    RestAssured.baseURI = "https://localhost:3000";
  }

  @Test
  public void updateUsingPut () {
    Posts post = new Posts();
    post.setId ("3");
    post.setTitle ("Hello Bhutan");
    post.setAuthor ("StaffWriter");

    given().body (post)
        .when ()
        .contentType (ContentType.JSON)
        .put ("/posts/3");
  }
}
```

For detailed explanation, you may check out the following link:
https://restservicestesting.blogspot.in/2016/10/automating-put-request-using-rest.html